# Error "... does not name a type" in a friend function in a union - why? How to fix?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, unions

I have the following code, which tries to define and call an output `operator` for a `union`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template <typename T>
union test
{
    using mytype = T;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, test<T> t)
    {
        stream << static_cast<mytype>(65);
    }
};

int main() {
    test<int> t;
    std::cout << t;
    return 0;
}
```

It fails compilation with the following error (actually, two errors):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, test)’:
prog.cpp:10:28: error: ‘mytype’ does not name a type
      stream << static_cast<mytype>(65);
                            ^~~~~~
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:15:10: error: non-template type ‘test’ used as a template
  test<int> t;
          ^
```

If I replace `union` by `struct`, it works correctly (prints `65`).

If I replace `friend` by a member function, it also works, but I must use this `friend` syntax because I want to make an output `operator`.

What else can I try to help the compiler understand my code?

I was using gcc 5.3.0; I then tried it on an online version of gcc 6.3 [here](https://ideone.com/ysT0ri), and it displays the same problems. It never displays any compilation errors on MS Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Looks like GCC fails to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is well-formed, so this is a GCC bug.

Besides switching to a conforming compiler, you could work around the bug by using a non-union class with anonymous union member instead of a plain union:

```
template <typename T>
struct test {
    using mytype = T;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, test<T> t)
        {
            stream << static_cast<mytype>(65);
            return stream;
        }
    union {
        // the union members
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is GCC bug. The function is defined inline, so name lookup should follow the same rules for member functions.

> **[basic.lookup.unqual]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.lookup.unqual) Name lookup for a name used in the definition of a friend
>   function ([class.friend]) defined inline in the class granting
>   friendship shall proceed as described for lookup in member function
>   definitions. If the friend function is not defined in the class
>   granting friendship, name lookup in the friend function definition
>   shall proceed as described for lookup in namespace member function
>   definitions.

My testing with GCC 8.2 [reproduced your error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EsEjoWyyPjQQSQ2o) with your code. But it had [no issues](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gd6MP5VOrkaTwAdo) when the `class-key` was switched from `union` to `struct`, and it also had [no problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U7lRWZfGQcFzwCpq) if the friend function was instead a member.

Of note is [GCC bug 85576](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85576), which reports the second error you got, and is undoubtedly related.

Comment: It seems to be issue with missing handling of friend of union. What such friendship gives?

Comment: @ÖöTiib - Same thing it gives for any other class type? The union can have private members. It can be subjected to operators that require the object on the right (like `<<`). Never made use of  it myself, but the standard doesn't differentiate as far as I can tell.